# Can i create Alert and Toast inside a contentObserver?

Tags: android, alert, toast

I'm unable to write the code to create alert and toast inside a ContentObserver of sms. I could not get the context for my ContentObserver. Somebody please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
 MyObserver yourObserver = new MyObserver(new Handler());

        ContentResolver contentResolver = this.getContentResolver();
        contentResolver.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms"),true, yourObserver);
```

&

```
class YourObserver extends ContentObserver {

    //Context context = new ContentObserver()
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    AlertDialog alert;
    public YourObserver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);
       Toast.makeText(???,"SENT..!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        System.out.println("Hey =++++++++++++++++++++++_______+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(???);
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure??");
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(???, "Okay",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                alert.cancel(); 
            }
        });
        alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the problem you are facing you should post the code.

Comment: " ??? " these are my problems.

Comment: yes check the below answer you need to pass the context to ContentObserver class.

Comment: Sir will you please let me know the procedure to send context to ContentObserver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass context of your Activity to the `ContentObserver` Class,

```
ContentResolver observer = this.getContentResolver();
        observer.registerContentObserver(SMS_URI, true,
                                   new MyObserver(new Handler(), this));
```

And the in the `MyObserver` class use the context,

```
   Activity mActivity;
    public MyContentObserver(Handler handler, Activity mActivity) {
        super(handler);
        this.mActivity= mActivity;
    }
```

Comment: Its working perfectly for the Toast but not for alert.When I include the code for alert it is giving **The Application has stopped unexpectedly** **Force Close**

Comment: Thread exiting with uncaught exception, 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main, Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Comment: 03-30 14:31:42.306: W/dalvikvm(1113): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
03-30 14:31:42.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1113): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-30 14:31:42.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1113): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
03-30 14:31:42.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):  at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:531)
03-30 14:31:42.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)

Comment: 03-30 14:31:42.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
03-30 14:31:42.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
03-30 14:31:42.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):  at com.cdac.service.MyObserver.onChange(MyObserver.java:54)
03-30 14:31:42.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):  at android.database.ContentObserver$NotificationRunnable.run(ContentObserver.java:43)
03-30 14:31:42.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)

Comment: 03-30 14:31:42.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-30 14:31:42.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-30 14:31:42.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-30 14:31:42.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-30 14:31:42.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)

Comment: 03-30 14:31:42.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-30 14:31:42.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-30 14:31:42.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1113):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 3):

You can use handler.post() to show Toast.

```
public SMSSentObserver(Handler handler, Context context) {
    super(handler);
    this.handler = handler;
    m_Context = context;
}

@Override
public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
    super.onChange(selfChange);
    handler.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            Toast.makeText(m_Context, "Toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: by the way, if you want to avoid to pass the Context in the constructor and your observer is a inner class of an activity, you can just use getApplicationContext() to get the context